# Using a Delphi TDictionary to use a string as index for a case statement

Tags: dictionary, delphi

Is it possible to use a `TDictionary` and a `case` statement like this?

It is just an idea, not sure if it works.

(not actual Delphi code )

```
mydic : tdictionary<string,smallint>
mydic := tdictionary<string,smallint>.create;
mydic.add('A option',1);
mydic.add('B option',2);
mydic.add('C option',3);

case someintegervariable of
  mydic('A option'): Begin
    //do stuff like case 1:
  end;

  mydic('B option'): Begin
    //do stuff like case 2:
  end; 

  mydic('C option'): Begin
    //do stuff like case 3:
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is not possible as case requires ordinairy constants in the expression.

Comment: No, the compiler must be able to resolve the cases. Clearly that is not the case in your example. Read [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Declarations_and_Statements)  scroll down to case statements. You could of course, however, use a `if..then..else` chain.

Comment: Apart from the above comments think about what would happen if the dictionary contains duplicate values. Which key would you pick then? Maybe you should consider implementing/using [bidirectional map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map). One such implementation can be found in [Generic collections library for Delphi](https://github.com/ghquant/delphi-coll/blob/master/src/Library/Collections.BidiMaps.pas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot do that in Delphi.  [`case` statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Case_Statements) require a compile-time numeric constant for each value that is being handled.

For what you are asking, you would have to either:

- use `if-else` statements:

```
var
  mydic : TDictionary<string, smallint>;
begin
  mydic := TDictionary<string, smallint>.Create;
  mydic.Add('A option', 1);
  mydic.Add('B option', 2);
  mydic.Add('C option', 3);

  if someintegervariable = mydic['A option'] then
  begin
    // do stuff for case 1 ...
  end
  else if someintegervariable = mydic['B option'] then
  begin
    // do stuff for case 2 ...
  end
  else if someintegervariable = mydic['C option'] then
  begin
    // do stuff for case 3 ...
  end;

  mydic.Free;
end;
```

- enumerate the dictionary:

```pascal
var
  mydic : TDictionary<string, smallint>;
  mypair: TPair<string, smallint>;
begin
  mydic := TDictionary<string, smallint>.Create;
  mydic.Add('A option', 1);
  mydic.Add('B option', 2);
  mydic.Add('C option', 3);

  for mypair in mydic do
  begin
    if mypair.Value = someintegervariable then
    begin
      if mypair.Key = 'A option' then
      begin
        // do stuff for case 1 ...
      end
      else if mypair.Key = 'B option' then
      begin
        // do stuff for case 2 ...
      end
      else if mypair.Key = 'C option' then
      begin
        // do stuff for case 3 ...
      end;
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  mydic.Free;
end;
```